# Existence of Countable Non-Closed set in an Infinite Completely Normal space

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

My question arises from a step in the proof of Theorem 3 in [Katětov's paper](https://eudml.org/doc/213165). In it, he states (where $P:=\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty P_n$ is a completely normal space) -

> *We may suppose $P$ infinite, so that it contains (the discontinuum of Cantor, and, therfore) a countable non-closed set.*

How did Katětov come about this? I'm assuming by *'the discontinuum of Cantor'*, he means what we call now the Cantor set. So, where did the Cantor set come from? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cantor set is homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ (discrete $\{0,1\}$) and this surely embeds into $P$ (we only need infinitely many $P_n$ with at least two points, and a two point set is homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}$ etc.)

Comment: Fun fact: during my PhD thesis research, I proved that the hyperspace $H(X)$ is completely normal iff $X$ is compact Hausdorff, based on this Katětov result. This was probably already folklore by that time...